# c++ nanopb Protobuff without <iostream>

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I have a protoBuff3 specification which looks something like

```
message MSG {
   string name = 1;
   repeated string data = 2;
}
```

And a options file that sets "MSG.data max_count:20"

I am trying to encode and decode protobuffs without using .

I am currently using **pb_ostream_from_buffer** and **pb_encode** however I when trying to link i get an error saying pb_ostream_..., pb_encode, pb_decode,... external symbols do not exist. I am able to find these functions defined in pb_encode.h and pb_decode.h

.Online i see reference to functions like 
**ParseFromString** and **SerializeToString**, however I can not find these function anywhere.

What is the proper way to serialize and serialize my message without iostreams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many protobuf libraries that are separate from each other. Generally you'd pick one and use that:

- [nanopb](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/): has functions such as `pb_ostream_from_buffer` and `pb_encode`.
- [Google's protobuf C++ library](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf): has functions such as `ParseFromString` and `SerializeToString`.

Either of these can be used for serializing and parsing messages from memory buffers. Additionally Google's library supports C++ iostreams, while nanopb supports a similar stream system implemented in C.

The error about "external symbols do not exist" suggests that you are not linking against the nanopb library code (`pb_encode.c`, `pb_decode.c` and `pb_common.c`). As usual, the `.h` files only contain function **declaration**, while you need to link against the `.c` files to provide the function **definition**.

Comment: Thanks allot, it was my dumb mistake. Being new to visual studios i forgot to add the .cpp files of protobuff to visual studios. Once i did that it worked